# Convert cumulative chart to non-cumulative using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to convert a cumulative chart to a non-cumulative chart. Basically I have demo to show you:

This is the cumulative graph:
http://jsfiddle.net/h1qq1rj8/

And this is the non cumulative graph:
http://jsfiddle.net/h1qq1rj8/2/

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },    
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },    
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },    
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of fruits'
            }
        },    
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },    
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },    
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [1, 8, 12, 13, 23], // I need to convert this data to non-cumulative
            stack: 'male'
        }]
    });
});
```

I have cumulated data, to convert it into non cumulative I am subtracting data in the backend, but due to that I am getting slow performance, isn't there a option to make the chart non cumulative in highcharts API itself ?

Edit:

I have one more graph where data is formatted in different way:
http://jsfiddle.net/h1qq1rj8/3/

Comment: The 3rd element should be 5 (which is 12-8) or 4 (which is 12-8-1)?

Comment: It should be 4, thanks for pointing it out, I have edited the question with fixed info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts will not do calculations on your data before drawing the chart, but you can move the calculation of this specific part from server-side to client side.

You can use the `reduce` function on the array to get the desired result:

```js
old_ar = [1, 8, 12, 13, 23]
new_ar = old_ar.reduce(function(a, b, c, d) { if (a.length) {a.push(d[c]-d[c-1])} else {a = [b]} return a;}, [])
console.log(new_ar)
```

For the 2nd style of data you can use this:

```js
old_ar = [[0,1],[1,8],[2,12],[3,13],[4,23]]
new_ar = old_ar.reduce(function(a, b, c, d) { if (a.length) {a.push([d[c][0], d[c][1]-d[c-1][1]])} else {a = [b]} return a;}, [])
console.log(new_ar)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, that did the trick! But I have one more graph where data is not formatted like that, it is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h1qq1rj8/3/

Comment: so basically you ask a question, but you meant something else? :) (you can use the `reduce` function for that as well... you just need to write it a bit differently)

Comment: added the 2nd style